# How can I remove a cancel button using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

Can any one suggest how I could remove the cancel button next to login button in the Facebook graph API for iPhone. Where does the code lie?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing this - messing around with the login dialogs is a big no-no for Facebook. The whole point of the SDK is that login dialogs look uniform across *all* applications.

Comment: Hey..It is posiible. But I dont know how to make it.

Comment: Hey... Its Possible, I have seen it in some Apps where there is no "Cancel" button.Why there is a need of it since it has already a "close" button at the top. Any one help please??